# Integrating $\sec^a\theta$ for all values. Does the Binomial Theorem hold for fractional exponents?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, binomial-theorem

I can integrate $\sec^a\theta$, where $a $ is even, without any difficulty. It is simply the integral of the binomial expansion of $(u^2+1)^{\frac{a-2}{2}}$. (Where $u=\tan\theta$)

When $a$ is odd, things get trickier.  I have to integrate the even function ( integral of  the binomial expansion of $(u^2+1)^{\frac{a-3}{2}},\space where \space u=\tan\theta,$) and the residual   $\sec\theta$ by parts. But this is messy.

So my question is: Does the binomial theorem hold for fractional exponents so that $$\int\sec^a\theta= \int \text{the binomial expansion of }(u^2+1)^{\frac{a-2}{2}},\space \text{where} \space u=\tan\theta,$$ for ALL rational values of "$a$".

Comment: I could barely imagine that it would hold if $a$ is irrational:)

Comment: True, edited to clarify.

Comment: If a is irrational and undefined boundaries, you will need an hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the binomial theorem holds for noninteger exponents; this is a famous discovery of Newton's.  See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

And, by the way, here's another method for the case of odd integers:
$$ \int \sec^{2k+1}\theta \,d\theta
= \int \frac1{\cos^{2k+2}\theta} \cos\theta\,d\theta
= \int \frac1{(1-u^2)^{k+1}} \,du
$$
and now deploy partial fractions.  (According to Eli Maor's book *Trigonometric Delights*, this is actually how Isaac Barrow first computed $\int\sec\theta\,d\theta$, which is notable as the first known use of partial fractions for integration.)

Comment: Just wondering, Is the unpaired 2 in the second expression supposed to be a 1?

Comment: No, that extra $\cos\theta$ is to cancel the $\cos\theta$ introduced up top.

Comment: Of course, don't know how I missed it.